# How to route to url.com/ControllerA/ControllerB/ControllerB's action in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

So I have a `ProjectsController` with the default route url.com/projects/action and I have a Controller for each Project like `MosaController`. The URL for the project should be url.com/projects/{ProjectName}/action, so in the Mosa example url.com/projects/Mosa/action.

I have set up a route in the RouteConfig that can solve this problem

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProjectViewRoute",
    url: "projects/{controller}/{action}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Projects", action = "Index" }
);
```

This works I can call url.com/projects/action and url.com/projects/Mosa/action and the correct controller is selected, but when I call the URL url.com/{ProjectName}/action it invokes the action, because of the default route. Is there a way to ignore the default route? Or is a there better way of concatenating controllers like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the default route for other portions of your app? If not, why not simply remove it and just have the ProjectViewRoute? Or consider creating "Projects" as an MVC "Area" (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-area-in-asp-net-mvc/).  This would eliminate the project-specific route outside of the Projects area.

Comment: Yes, I do need the default route for other controllers

Comment: Then I would suggest using an Area. It's the most straight-forward way to handle this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will definitely try areas, but so far it sounds like it is the right thing.

Comment: Great.  If that works out, I would appreciate it if you would mark my response as the answer.